# doxygen and "old style" class list

Tags: c++, doxygen

I noticed that new versions of doxygen (I have 1.8.1.1) produce class lists where the nesting is done hierarchically, such as:

- namespace

  - MyClass1
  - MyClass2

e.g. http://www.itk.org/Doxygen/html/annotated.html

I much rather want to have the old style of the class list:

- namespace::MyClass1
- namespace::MyClass2

e.g. http://trilinos.sandia.gov/packages/docs/r10.8/packages/tpetra/doc/html/annotated.html

Is there a setting in the doxyfile with which I can get the old style?

---

My reasoning behind this request is, that I usually search for my C++ classes in by searching for "namespace::MyClass". Usually even "::My" finds the right class very fast. In the new style I no longer know how to do that.

Comment: Nice question. This would be a really nice feature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally the annotated index should have "detail level" navigation, as you can see here:
http://www.nsnam.org/doxygen/annotated.html
Clicking on the highest level (5 in the example) will expand the whole index, and then you can easily search for classes.

Another way is using the Annotated Index:
http://www.nsnam.org/doxygen/classes.html

Comment: "Clicking on the highest level (5 in the example) will expand the whole index, and then you can easily search for classes.". Well if you want to search for `MyClass` in namespace `MyNS` then you first have to search for `MyNS` (in this process you also find if a classname contains `MyNS` and then you search for `MyClass` and you will also find classes like `IAmNotMyClass`. In the old style, searching for `MyNS::MyClass` (or even `::My`) will get you immediately where you want to be.

Comment: Don't get me wrong, the new style looks useful for browsing through and exploring, but the old list was much more machine-searchable.

Comment: As for the Annotated Index, unfortunately the order is `Classname <Template Args> (namespace)`. So if I want to search for `MyVeryVeryVeryLongClassname` in `MySN`, then I would have to search for `MyVeryVeryVeryLongClassname (MySN)` instead of say `MySN::My`. Even more annoying is that all template args are in between :-(